# Rangeroundbands making my axes too wide

Tags: d3.js, scale

I am hoping to have my axes be the same width as my area chart. My axes, though, are slightly wider than the chart.

See below:

[image]

Instead, I am hoping to have them like this -- end to end:

[image]

My code is like the following:

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 15, bottom: 30, left: 15},
        width = 130 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 170 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

      var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .rangeRoundBands([0, width],1);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x).tickSize(0,0)
        .tickValues([])
        .orient("bottom");
```

Every thing else follows from these values and the x() scale.

Comment: Hmm, you would need to extend the domain past the last tick marks by half the width of the labels. This isn't something you can do easily with D3 -- maybe simply select the two extreme labels and move them accordingly instead?

Comment: I ended up just appending them as text objects. Another way was to make two axes, one for text, one for a line.